# Elo Matchmaking that also consider waiting time

Tags: algorithm

I have been searching the internet for a few days with various queries, attempting to find an algorithm that is used for a matchmaking Elo service.  I implemented a basic Elo system into a game plugin I am writing.  The next major step is to try and create an automated matchmaking system that has a pool of players that are looking for matches, and the matchmaking system tries to pair players together who are close in Elo.  The main dilemma is giving priority to players that have been waiting longer versus a shorter amount of time.

Are there any implementations of such a system that I cannot seem to find?

EDIT: I also spent some time searching SOF as well.  Checked all the related questions, didn't seem to find anything helpful.  I am also completely open to trying different rating systems as well, the main dilemma I am having is the matchmaking side of things.

Comment: Elo is not an acronym so it should not all be capitalized. It's named after [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpad_Elo).

Comment: `Distance = (Elo2 - Elo1) - (Time2 + Time1) * alpha;`

Comment: Can you start a game after a pair(ing) is available or is the number of slots limited? Are there many players? Is it critical, if some pairings happen again and again (like the two top players)? Or should the matching system create more variety on purpose? Is there a maximum distance of Elo for a pairing or does it change with waiting time?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you use a distance calculation function to match players. If you use the invert of the amount of time a user has waited as a weight to your distance calculation function, it should match people who have waited longer first.